# Display the image files from the storage

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm on Laravel 5.3 and I'm having trouble rendering the file images from Laravel Storage to my html/blade.

My filesystems.php default driver

```
'default' => 'public'
```

How to render the file images from the 'Storage' to view/html/blade

I tried this,

```
//path for image from the storage
Route::get('/app/system/sale-items/item/{username}/{item_id}/{image}', function($image,$item_id,$username)
{
    $path = storage_path().'/app/public/'.$username.'/'.$item_id.'/'. $image;
    if (file_exists($path)) { 
        return Response::download($path);
    }
});
```

but seem's not working like the image is not showing, it fails to retrieved the image from the 'Storage'. Any help, ideas please?

Comment: try using `storage_path()` helper https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-storage-path

Comment: try something like this  Route::get('images/{filename}', function ($filename)
{
    return Image::make(storage_path() . '/' . $filename)->response();
});

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out already, I just use

```
//path for image from the storage
Route::get('/app/system/sale-items/item/{username}/{item_id}/{image}', function($username,$item_id,$image)
{
    $path = storage_path().'/app/public/'.$username.'/'.$item_id.'/'. $image;
    if (file_exists($path)) { 
        return Response::download($path);
    }
});
```